# How to use public NSURL Variable

Tags: macos, swift

I'm new to Swift and Xcode overall,
I want to create a new public NSURL variable which I want to use later in my code to give it value and use that value later from it. like below :

```
class AddUrlViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var txtPath: NSTextField!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  @IBAction func btnFileDialog(sender: NSButton) {
    let myFiledialog:NSOpenPanel = NSOpenPanel()
        myFiledialog.canChooseDirectories = true
        myFiledialog.canChooseFiles = false

    var returnCode:NSInteger = myFiledialog.runModal()

    if (returnCode == NSOKButton) {
        /////////// Use it here
        var directoryUrl = myFiledialog.URL?.absoluteURL
    }
  }

  @IBAction func btnStart(sender: NSButton) {
    //////////// Use it here
  }
}
```

How should I achieve this the best way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply define the variable as a property outside of the function scope -

```
class AddUrlViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var txtPath: NSTextField!
var directoryUrl:NSURL?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  @IBAction func btnFileDialog(sender: NSButton) {
    let myFiledialog:NSOpenPanel = NSOpenPanel()
        myFiledialog.canChooseDirectories = true
        myFiledialog.canChooseFiles = false

    var returnCode:NSInteger = myFiledialog.runModal()

    if (returnCode == NSOKButton) {
        /////////// Use it here
        self.directoryUrl = myFiledialog.URL?.absoluteURL
    }
  }

  @IBAction func btnStart(sender: NSButton) {
    if (self.directoryUrl != nil) {

    //////////// Use it here
    }
  }
}
```